# Efficient way to create array of all digit strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

I want to create an array of digits.
I'm currently just hardcoding it as such

`const digitGeneration = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];`

I know in other languages I can create an array using the range operator for ints. I was hoping I could do something like that in JS. Instead, I came up with this

`const digitGeneration = [...Array(10).keys()].map(digit => digit.toString());`

Anyone have a simpler way? Or is it not worth it and better to just hardcode it and save execution time for efficiency?

Comment: Efficiency comes when you have a bottleneck and here you are trying do a micro-optimization which won't make any noteable difference.

Comment: `[...Array(10).keys()].map(String)` or `Object.keys(Array(10).fill())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spread on a string:

```
[..."0123456789"]
```

If you need more numbers (with more digits), then I would go for `Array.from`, using its callback argument, and mapping with `String`:

```
Array.from({length: 20}, (_, i) => String(i+1));
```

If you would execute this millions of times, then nothing will beat the original hard-coded array literal. But for other "normal" uses, this is quite acceptable.

Comment: This kind of breaks at 10 though, but if 0-9 was the only requirement its not so bad.

Comment: The OP wrote "array of digits", and title says "all digit strings", so I don't see how this means arrays of multi-digit numbers. Anyway I added the solution I would use for multi-digit numbers.

Comment: this is the canonical answer ...

Answer (score 2):

With JavaScript, unless you're building a CPU-intensive library or a function that will be called thousands of times per second, microoptimizations are pointless. I prefer clarity to code length, so I would probably do it like this:

```js
const digitGeneration = Array(10);
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  digitGeneration[i] = i.toString();
}
```

The way you did it is perfectly fine, though. I suppose if you wanted a general purpose `range()` like in python, you could create a generator:

```js
function* range(startVal, endVal, step = 1) {
  const stepSign = Math.sign(step);
  if (stepSign === 0) {
    throw new TypeError('step cannot be 0');
  }
  if (arguments.length == 0) {
    throw new TypeError('no range specified');
  }
  if (arguments.length == 1) {
    endVal = startVal;
    startVal = 0;
  }
  for (let i = startVal; Math.sign(endVal - i) === stepSign; i += step) {
    yield i;
  }
}
```

Since no array is created, for iteration purposes this is as efficient as a for loop, even for massive ranges.

```js
for (const value of range(10000, 1, -1)) {
  console.log(value);
}
// Outputs 10000...2 separated by newline without taking 10KB of memory
```

Or you could create an array, like you're trying to do:

```js
const digitGeneration = [...range(10)].map(e => e.toString());
// This is ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: The range iterator is certainly going to be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
console.log(Array(20).fill().map((_, i) => String(i + 1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could spread a number.

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this; i++) yield i.toString();
};

console.log([...10]);
```

Comment: But now you cannot spread numeric types any more... Changing the Number prototype seems a bad idea, as it affects all other code.